# Updated Docker images and bootstrapping

Tags: node, docker

I recently had to reboot my machine, and upon restarting the tezos services (using the `alphanet.sh start` command) it automatically pulled an updated image wiping out my previous context which meant it had to bootstrap again. Is this the expected behavior whenever a new docker image is used? Can I prevent the script from automatically downloading the updated image so I can at least try to backup the context before it wipes all of the data?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

If you prefer to temporarily disable automatic updates, you just have to set an environment variable:

`export TEZOS_ALPHANET_DO_NOT_PULL=yes`